# How to make method return value if panic happen and processed in defer func(){...}() in golang

Tags: go

My function must return a string whatever success or panic.

```
func getDBStoreStatus() string{
    var replyMessage string
    defer func() string{ 
        if err := recover(); err != nil {  
            replyMessage = "Error happend." 
        }
    return replyMessage
    }()

    //do something to store row into DB
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user1:password@/databaseName?charset=utf8") 
    newMessage, err := db.Prepare("INSERT .............
    res, err := newMessage.Exec(...........
    if err != nil { 
        panic(err)
    }
    replyMessage = "OK"
    return replyMessage
}
```

How can I return a string, if the panic processed by defer section?
You can see the return statement in defer section doesn't work properly.

Comment: Don't panic, and re-use your database pool across your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your return parameter, then you can set it in the `defer` method:

```
func getDBStoreStatus() (replyMessage string) {
    defer func(){ 
        if err := recover(); err != nil {  
            replyMessage = "Error happend." 
        }
    }()

    //do something to store row into DB
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user1:password@/databaseName?charset=utf8") 
    newMessage, err := db.Prepare("INSERT .............
    res, err := newMessage.Exec(...........
    if err != nil { 
        panic(err)
    }
    replyMessage = "OK"
    return replyMessage
}
```

See the Go Blog post on [Defer, Panic and Recover](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover):

> 3. Deferred functions may read and assign to the returning function's named return values.
>
>    In this example, a deferred function increments the return value i
>      after the surrounding function returns. Thus, this function returns 2:
>
>    ```
>    func c() (i int) {
>        defer func() { i++ }()
>        return 1
>    }
>    ```

I don't really see the point, though. You could just do:

```
    if err != nil { 
        return "Error happend."
    }
```

instead of `panic(err)`.

Comment: The question just is an abstraction of my reality problem. I need do many other things to handle multiple errors. Your solution works! Thank you!